# Errors when running "npm install" on cloned vuejs project

Tags: ubuntu, npm, vue.js, npm-install, grpc

Nodejs v4.2.6,
Npm v3.5.2

Recently did a system reset of windows 10 and then installed Ubuntu using dual boot. I'm relatively new to the Ubuntu operating system and only know enough Linux commands to get me around. When I run npm install in my VueJs project directory I get this:

```
> grpc@1.9.0 install /home/george/code/bedal/portal.barcodexchange.com/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.3
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! grpc@1.9.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.9.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the grpc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs grpc
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls grpc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/george/code/bedal/portal.barcodexchange.com/npm-debug.log
```

Despite the errors I tried running "npm run dev" in the same directory and this is what I get:

```
> barcode_portal@1.0.0 dev /home/george/code/bedal/portal.barcodexchange.com
> node build/dev-server.js

sh: 1: node: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! barcode_portal@1.0.0 dev: `node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the barcode_portal@1.0.0 dev script 'node build/dev-server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the barcode_portal package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/dev-server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs barcode_portal
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls barcode_portal
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/george/code/bedal/portal.barcodexchange.com/npm-debug.log
```

This is what my file directory looks like in the VueJs project:

```
.   
.babelrc  
config     
.editorconfig  
.eslintrc.js   
.firebaserc  
.gitignore  
node_modules   
package.json   
README.md  
.vscode
..  
build     
debug.log  
.eslintignore  
firebase.json  
.git         
index.html  
npm-debug.log  
.postcssrc.js  
src        
yarn.lock
```

Mind you the project worked fine on the Windows install but now I'm having trouble starting everything on Ubuntu. Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to install node.js

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install node.js on your system as Roland pointed out. Node has directions [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager).

```shell
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Alternatively (and in my opinion, the best way) is to use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

Then

```
nvm install node && nvm use node
```

This allows you to switch node versions quickly if need be.

Comment: I've already installed node.js prior to posting this. I installed it via

sudo apt-get install node.js

Is there a problem with this method?

nodejs -v

Gives me the version so I know it's installed

Comment: The node.js available via apt is fairly outdated, and installs as `nodejs` and not `node` which is what most package scripts are going to try and execute. I'd recommend removing that package and installing via the methods above.